# Avoid unneccessary re-rendering in React dynamic nested components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, performance, react-hooks, react-functional-component

The state for my project includes a list of nested animals eg:

```
    {"europe":{"air":{name:"warbler", points:0}}}
```

My components are generated based on this data, and at the lowest level (the animal itself), there is a button which is currently triggering a series of callbacks to the highest level, starting a dispatch to the reducer. Every time a button is clicked, all the components from every continent re-render.
Would it be better to implement useContext, even though every level of component requires some amount of data from the state object?
I tried to implement useCallback, to prevent re-rendering but I didn't know which callbacks were causing it. What would be the best way to optimize rendering a series of nested components (without redux)?

Inside **App** component

```
 {Object.entries(state.animalData).map(([continent, areas]) => (
                    <Continent
                        key={continent}
                        areas={areas}
                        totals={state.totals.continents[continent]}
                        handleVote={(
                            num: number,
                            animal: string,
                            area: string
                        ) => triggerChange(num, animal, area, continent)}
                    />
                ))}
```

Inside **Continent** component

```
               <Area
                    key={area}
                    area={area}
                    animals={animals}
                    onVote={(num: number, animal: string) =>
                        handleVote(num, animal, area)
                    }
                  />
```

Inside **Area** component

```
    {animals.map(animal => (
                <Animal
                    key={animal.name}
                    animal={animal}
                    voted={(num: number) => onVote(num, animal.name)}
                />
            ))}
```

Inside **Animal** component

```
          <div>
            <h4>{animal.name}</h4>
            <div>
                <button onClick={voted(+1)}> Upvote </button>
                <button onClick={voted(-1)}> Downvote </button>
            </div>
            <h4>{`${animal.points} Points`}</h4>
            <hr />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your components trigger a re render because you are using inline defined functions everywhere and those aren't referentially stable. You can use the `useCallback` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook to prevent re renders.

But you could also use a context provider (as you suggested) which holds the `voted` callback. That way you don't have to use prop drilling to get the function to the component where it is needed.

The basic solution for this is explained in detail here: https://medium.com/@jeromefranco/how-to-avoid-prop-drilling-in-react-7e3a9f3c8674

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! So would it be a good idea to wrap all the inline functions created here in useCallback, I couldn't figure out whether I just had to wrap the lowest-level function, or the highest-level function to prevent re-renders since the child triggers the chain, but the parent function is rendered first.

Comment: That would be the highest level function. Then you just pass it down as a prop value.

Comment: Since the highest level function accepts parameters how would I got about this, I've added const triggerChange = React.useCallback((
        num: number,
        animal: string,
        area: string,
        continent: string
    ) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'vote',
            payload: {
                num,
                animal,
                area,
                continent,
            },
        });
    },[]); but it still seems to re-render, any ideas? thanks again for this

Comment: What exactly re renders? Can you provide a working example via codepen oder codesandbox? We don't know all the logic flow in your code, so it's hard to say what the issue is.